# Solutions to the Diophantine equation $a^xy+x=c$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Fix positive integers $a,c$ with $a>2$. Is it possible that the Diophantine equation
$$a^xy+x=c$$
has infinitely many solutions (in positive integers $x$ and $y$)?

Comment: Do you have any experimental material? Mostly I find either no or one solution. For $a=3$ there are at least two solutions when $c=85, 166, 247, 328, 409, 490, 571$; for $a=4$ there are at least two solutions with $c=1029$. Do you know any other cases? In particular, do you know any cases when there are more than two solutions?

Comment: I haven't numerically investigated the equation. I assumed that this was easy or intractable, and I am not an expert in these things. But I appreciate your effort and enthusiasm!

Comment: I don't know about the number of solutions. But that number is definitely always finite. x must be at most c since $a^x y$ is positive, and $y$ must be at most $c$ by similar logic. So unless I'm missing something here, for fixed c, there are at most $c^2$ solutions even if a is allowed to vary over positive integers (not even $a>2$).  It isn't hard to improve this to $\frac{c^2}{2}$ given your restrictions.

Comment: The smallest $c$ such that the Diophantine equation $3^xy+x=c$ has three positive solutions is $c=38180350917190281105854137945200663220016794$. The solutions correspond to $x=1, 4, 85$.

Answer (score 2):

As was observed by @JoshuaZ, for given $a, c\in\mathbb{N}$, the equation $(*)\; a^xy+x=c$ has only finitely many solutions. On the other hand, I show that for any $a$ and any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ one can find $c=c(a, N)$ such that the equation $(*)$ has at least $N$ solutions. To see this, let us observe that $(*)$ has a solution if and only if
$$
c\equiv x\pmod{a^x}.
$$
Thus, to show that $(*)$ it is enough to find posittive integers $x_{1}<x_{2}<\ldots<x_{N}$ such that the system of congruences
$$
(**)\quad c\equiv x_{1}\pmod{a^{x_{1}}},\; c\equiv x_{2}\pmod{a^{x_{2}}},\;\ldots, \;c\equiv x_{N}\pmod{a^{x_{N}}}
$$
has a solution.
Applying general form of chinese remainder theorem we need to find $x_{1}, x\ldots, x_{N}$ such that for each $i, j\in\{1,\ldots, N\}, i\neq j$ we have $\gcd(a^{x_{i}},a^{x_{j}})=a^{x_{i}}|x_{j}-x_{i}$. To construct suitable sequence it is is enough to define
$$
x_{1}=1, x_{n}=a^{x_{n-1}}+x_{n-1}
$$
and observe (using simple induction on $k$) that
$$
x_{n+k}=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a^{x_{n+i}}+x_{n}.
$$
This clearly implies that $a^{x_{i}}|x_{j}-x_{i}$ for $j>i$. Computing now the solution $c=c(a, N)$ of the system $(**)$ we get that there are positive integers $y_{1}, \ldots, y_{N}$ such that the equation $(*)$ has solutions $(x_{1}, y_{1}), \ldots, (x_{N}, y_{N})$.